# how do you remove text from Pandas styled object while keeping the style in place

Tags: pandas, pandas-styles

I have a styled object that some of the cells have nan values. I need to remove the nan values while I keep the style in place.

[image]

if I do this:

```
new_df.data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

this removes the nan values as well as the style.

Is there a way to keep the style while removing nan values from the Pandas styled object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I noticed your issue is with the styles.

You could use this oneliner:

```
styler_obj.data.where(~styler_obj.data.isna(), '', inplace=True)
```

If you don't care about the styles you can simply use `DataFrame.replace` like this:

```
df.replace('NaN', '', inplace=True)
```

Or get a little bit fancy using types from `Numpy` like this:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
```

Comment: it is not data frame. It is a data frame styled object that has nan values that I need to remove while keeping the style in tact.

Comment: I get this error: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: That's because you need to get the dataframe object from the styler to work with it, I have updated the answer once again.

Comment: Also it's not a good practice to name styled objects with regular dataframe variable names, consider adding styled or styler in the variable name.

Comment: "styler_obj.data = " does not work. if I remove data, it works but removes the style while updating the sytled object data

Comment: @user1471980 You could use the .where method, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255221/discussion-between-user1471980-and-ahmad-hamdi).

Comment: TypeError: cannot do implace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
#df from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061724

import numpy as np

TARGET = "Percent_Utilized"

def color(ser):
    conds = [ser.gt(80), ser.between(50, 80, inclusive="right"), ser.isnull()]
    vals = ["background-color: red", "background-color: yellow", ""]
    return np.select(conds, vals, default="background-color: green")

s = (
    df.style
        .apply(color, subset=TARGET)
        .format("{:.0f}%", na_rep="", subset=TARGET)
        .format(na_rep="", subset="Model") # optional
)
```

Output :

[image]